# Variable in html python

Tags: python

I want to be able to use variables like returnJson["hdrul"] in the html, but I'm not sure how.

```
out = open("nasa.html", "w")
link = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=api"
x = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
url = x.read()

returnJson = json.loads(url)
print('\n')
print(returnJson["hdurl"])


html = """<html>
<head></head> 
<body> 
<img src= returnJson["hdurl"]>
</body> 


</html> """

out.write(html)
out.close()
```

Comment: You should use string formatting or f-strings if possible.

Comment: @costaparas f-strings are a better alternative.

Comment: @sagar Yes, I agree, f-strings are the preferred way. If you look closely, there are many answers in that duplicate link, including f-strings. So there's really nothing new being asked here. All the standard methods have already been explained in-depth many times over.

Comment: @costaparas i agree

Comment: I'll mess around with both and see which works better, but the link is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of f-string that you can use:

```
data = 596
html = f"""<html>
<head></head> 
<body> 
The data is : {data}
</body> 
"""
```

Whatever is in curly brackets get interpreted as normal python.